# How can I change the default value for a text input widget in Databricks?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a text input widget where a user can enter a date.

```
CREATE WIDGET TEXT FromDate DEFAULT '2021-09-27'
```

This works fine, except that I would like the default to *always* be **yesterday's** date.

I can, of course, do this:

```
SELECT CAST(date_sub(CAST(current_timestamp() as DATE), 1) AS STRING)
```

which returns `2021-09-27` as expected, so I was hoping that this would work for the widget:

```
CREATE WIDGET TEXT FromDate DEFAULT (SELECT CAST(date_sub(CAST(current_timestamp() as DATE), 1) AS STRING))
```

However, this results in:

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
no viable alternative at input 'CREATE WIDGET'(line 1, pos 7)

== SQL ==
CREATE WIDGET TEXT From DEFAULT (SELECT CAST(date_sub(CAST(current_timestamp() as DATE), 1) AS STRING))
-------^^^
```

How can I change the default value for a text input widget in Databricks so that it always retuns yesterday's date ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is impossible - you can specify subquery only to populate the `CHOICES` argument of the Dropdown widget. Text widgets are accepting only literal value.

Per [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html#widgets-in-sql):

> To specify the selectable values in a **dropdown widget** in SQL, you can write a sub-query. The first column of the resulting table of the sub-query determines the values.

The possible workaround would be to create widget using the Python, where there are more possibilities for calculation of the default values.